# Is a simple function thread safe

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety

if I have this type of program level function

```
def returnInt(s):
    return int(float(s))
```

and it ended up being called by 2 separate threads at the same time would it be "thread safe" or do I need to add as a function in both thread classes
e.g

```
class StepperControl(threading.Thread):
....

    def returnInt(self,s):
        return int(float(self.s))

....

class BounceControl(threading.Thread):
....

    def returnInt(self,s):
        return int(float(self.s))

....
```

Simon

Comment: Why shouldn't it be? It might not do what you think though, it will basically ignore the parameter you pass and return `self.s`. If you want it to return `self.bla` or `s = "bla"` you'd need to use `getattr(self, s)` instead.

Comment: It has no side effects and it doesn't reference any variable/memory outside its scope so it is inherently thread safe.

Comment: @tibor - Ta :) Is you add you answer as an answer instead of a comment then I can mark up it up as accepted :)

Comment: @filmor - forgive the wrong thread code syntax - I just threw it in as a pseudo example :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, It is thread-safe, as it does not access or attempt to change anything outside itself.